# WPF datagrid combobox with list of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a List of Objects

```
class myObject 
{
  string Name
  string ID
}
```

Now I want to bind the list into the datagrid combobox, with the name of the objects visible. Currently I solve this with overriding the function `ToString() { return Name; }`.

Any other ideas?

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If you solved this with overriding, why are you looking for another way then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DisplayMemberPath` of the `ComboBox` or the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to "Name" and make sure that `Name` is a *public property* of the `myObject` class:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```